# Add value to JSON array in java

Tags: spring-boot

```
            results = {ArrayList@22831}  size = 11
             0 = {LinkedTreeMap@22840}  size = 36
              0 = {LinkedTreeMap$Node@22854} "id" -> "7.0"
              1 = {LinkedTreeMap$Node@22855} "version" -> "0.0"
              2 = {LinkedTreeMap$Node@22856} "family" -> " size = 9",
        .
        .
        .

              35 = "formattedValue"-> "[  
       {  
          "subCondition":"default",
          "maxGuarantee":{  
             "amount":2500000,
             "currencyCode":"USD"
          },
          "minGuarantee":{  
             "amount":30000,
             "currencyCode":"USD"
          },
          "minLoanAmount":{  
.
.
.
```

I need to add

```
 "minGuaranteePerPerson":{  
             "amount":30000,
             "currencyCode":"USD"
          },
```

to add the bottom of that array i gave at the first. So, it will be in `formattedValue`. At the end, it will be like this:

```
35 = "formattedValue"-> "[  
           {  
              "subCondition":"default",
              "maxGuarantee":{  
                 "amount":2500000,
                 "currencyCode":"USD"
              },
              "minGuarantee":{  
                 "amount":30000,
                 "currencyCode":"USD"
              },
              "minLoanAmount":{  
...
     },"minGuaranteePerPerson":{  
                 "amount":30000,
                 "currencyCode":"USD"
              },
```

I tried this:

```
 final JsonObject json = (JsonObject) results.get(i).get("formattedValue").toString()
```

but it gave error of like `Can't cast gson to my Object type`

Probably because it is not `JSONOBject`, it is array.

```
results
```

is like this

```
ArrayList<LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>> results;
```

I need to first get that JSon, that to add my variable but i can not get.

Can not use `objectmapper` because there is no DTO or class. I need to do with add operations.

When i do

```
new JSONArray(results)
```

it shows:

```
[{"code":"KOBI","componentBases":[],"formattedValue":"[{\"subCondition\":\"default\",\"minGuaranteeRate\":\"15\",\"maxGuaranteeRate\":\"25\",\"maxGuaranteeAmount\":{\"amount\":2500000,\"currencyCode\":\"TRY\"},//and so on
```

when i do

```
new JSONArray(results).getJSONObject(0)
```

it shows only first one.

```
new JSONObject(results)
```

this shows `empty false`

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to help you if you don't tell us what JSON library you are using nor provide "clean" JSON format input. Also, it looks like you don't want to add your data to an array but to an object contained in an array.

Basically, what you have to do is to navigate to the element you want to modify, e.g.

```
JsonObject formattedValueFirst = results.get(0).get("formattedValue").get(0);
```

and then modify it, e.g.

```
JsonObject minGuaranteePerPersonObject = new JsonObject();
minGuaranteePerPersonObject.addProperty("amount", 30000);
minGuaranteePerPersonObject.addProperty("currencyCode", "USD");
formattedValueFirst.addProperty("minGuaranteePerPerson", minGuaranteePerPersonObject);
```

Comment: When i do this `new JsonObject(results.get(0).get("formattedValue"))`, it says invalid argument and last get(0) is not coming. Jackson library is `jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar`

Comment: After re-reading your question I see that you are not dealing with `JSON*` Objects but have ArrayLists and so on. This means that `.get("formattedValue")` will return the type `Object`. You have to find out what the actual (run-time) type of this Object is and cast it to something more usable first.